# Advanced search with default search in laravel datatable

Tags: php, laravel-5

I implemented custom search facility to my project using laravel Yajra datatable package. after implement this feature default regex search function not working. I cannot identify the issue. please help me to resolve this immedietly. my code is,

### javascript code in blade file

```
function search(){
$("#cus_cat_price_list_details").show();
    $('#cus_cat_price_table').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        destroy: true,
        searching: true,
        ajax: {
            url: "{{ url('/cus_cat_price_list/search') }}",
            data: function (d) {
                d.cus_name = $('#cus_name').val();
                d.pro_id = $('#pro_id').val();
            }
        },
        columns: [
            { data: 'cus_cat', name: 'cus_cat' },
            { data: 'pro_no', name: 'pro_no' },
            { data: 'pro_name', name: 'pro_name' },
            { data: 'cash_price', name: 'cash_price', className: 'text-right' },
            { data: 'credit_price', name: 'credit_price', className: 'text-right' },
            { data: 'cus_cat_price_date', name: 'cus_cat_price_date' },
        ]
    });

 }
```

### Controller

```
public function search(Request $request){

    $cusCatPriceList = DB::table('customer_category_wise_price_list AS ccpl')
    ->join('product as p', 'p.pro_id','ccpl.pro_id')
    ->select([
        DB::raw("'SR' AS cus_cat"),
        'ccpl.pro_no',
        'p.pro_name',
        'ccpl.cash_price',
        'ccpl.credit_price',
        'ccpl.cus_cat_price_date',
    ])
    ->whereNull('ccpl.deleted_at')
    ->groupBy('ccpl.cus_cat_price_id');

    return Datatables::of($cusCatPriceList)
    ->filter(function ($query) use ($request) {
        if ($request->has('pro_id') && $request->get('pro_id') != "0") {
            $query->where('ccpl.pro_id', '=', "{$request->get('pro_id')}");
        }
    })
    ->make(true);
}
```

Comment: Try passing `true` as the second argument for the filter method `filter(function () {}, true)`

Comment: I added it. but I'm getting SQL error message like sqlstate 42000

Answer (score 1):

you should use a `return` in filter :

```
return Datatables::of($cusCatPriceList)
->filter(function ($query) use ($request) {
    if ($request->has('pro_id') && $request->get('pro_id') != "0") {
        return $query->where('ccpl.pro_id', '=', "{$request->get('pro_id')}");
    }
})
->make(true);
```

Comment: **You can use this code block inside filturer function. it worked for me**

`if ($request->has('search') && ! is_null($request->get('search')['value']) ) {`
`$regex = $request->get('search')['value'];`
`return $query->where(function($query) use($regex){`
`$queryNew->where('ccpl.pro_no', 'like', '%' . $regex . '%');`
`});`
`}`

Answer (score 1):

1. in your controller is better use relations expect this query then use this :

```
     return datatables()->eloquent(your_relation)
     addColumn()    //your columns
     ->raw(array)   //for your html codes because laravel return it as a code.
     ->filter(call back function)  //like your filter that write for it
     ->toJson();
```

Note : some times `$request->has()`  donot return  use full caracter , like if your variable in js return "undifined" has return true.